# Does scientific notation affect Perl's precision?

Tags: perl, numbers, precision

I encountered a weird behaviour in Perl. The following subtraction should yield zero as result (which it does in Python):

```
print 7.6178E-01 - 0.76178
-1.11022302462516e-16
```

Why does it occur and how to avoid it?

P.S. Effect appears on "v5.10.0 built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi" (Ubuntu 9.04) and "v5.8.9 built for darwin-2level" (Mac OS 10.6)

Comment: Works fine for me, I get 0 (v5.8.8, Mac OSX).

Comment: I have two Perls on this machine here - a local build of 5.8.8 that works correctly, and the one that comes built in - that exhibits your issue.

Comment: Occurs on 5.10.1, MSWin32-x86-multi-thread as well (Strawberry Perl 5.10.1.0).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not that scientific notation affects the precision so much as the limitations of floating point notation represented in binary. See the answers to the [perlfaq4](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq4.html). This is a problem for any language that relies on the underlying architecture for number storage.

- [Why am I getting long decimals (eg, 19.9499999999999) instead of the numbers I should be getting (eg, 19.95)?](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#Why_am_I_getting_lon)
- [Why is int() broken?](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#Why_is_int_broken_)

If you need better number handling, check out the [bignum](http://perldoc.perl.org/bignum.html) pragma.

Comment: Ok, use bignum does the trick. However, I refuse to accept this behaviour as normal, regardless of any binary representation issues. Any other language handles this correctly.

Comment: Not all languages store numbers the same, and I didn't say anything about it being normal.

Comment: Simon - any language that isn't demonstrating these sort of issues in at least SOME corner cases is either not using the CPU floating-point instructions or is not handling floating-point numbers correctly. Unfortunately, incorrect handling of numbers is relatively normal (at leats as far as conversion between base-10 fractional numbers and floating-point numbers).

Comment: This answer is true, but doesn't address the question of why two different literals expressing the same number are being stored as two different representations.

Comment: They aren't the same number to the computer. You translate them to mean the same number, but that's not how it works in the silicon. David M already explained that.

Comment: I wouldn't really say David *explained* it, Brian. Rather, he offered some ideas about what *might* be true. Is his suggestion *really* how the compiler parses scientific-notation literals? Is it code shared by all Perl interpreters, or do some versions do it differently?

Comment: The read code for yourself. It's all in either perl.h or numeric.c. It boils down to who implements your atof, which depends on how you compiled the source. No matter which way you compile, you're at the mercy of how the local architecture handles multiplication or division. What David M. describes is what Perl does.